# Android Chat, Messenger

Tags: android, listview, chat

I created a chat which can only send a text messages and save it in database. I use listView to show messages.

How I can send a images, audio, videos together.  How to combine text images in one view. To create a new view, and overview onDraw. Have you got some ideas? Code?

Comment: Can you show code for what you've tried so far?